# Validation Error from Companies House (UK Government)

Tags: php, xml

I want to extracting financial information of different companies within 2010-2015 from Company House website and drawing a chart like the attached image by using those data.
but I don't know the exact this information and get error. Can anybody help me? Companies House provide sample [XML request](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/filinghist_req.xml) and [sample XML response](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/filinghist_reply.xml).

My error when I send request to xml gateway:

> string(1288) " 1.0
>       error 2016-08-29T13:04:36-00:00 CHMD5
>       CH_XML_Gateway 100 fatal XML failed schema validation: XML error: Invalid document structure line 1 column 1 " string(0) ""

This is my xmlcode:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GovTalkMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch.xsd" xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:gt="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
    <MessageDetails>
      <Class>FilingHistory</Class>
      <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
      <TransactionID>11452543233</TransactionID>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
      <IDAuthentication>
   <SenderID>my sender id</SenderID>
        <Authentication>
          <Method>CHMD5</Method>
          <Value>my pass</Value>
        </Authentication>
      </IDAuthentication>
      <EmailAddress>email company</EmailAddress>
    </SenderDetails>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <FilingHistoryRequest xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/FilingHistory-v2-1.xsd">
    <CompanyNumber>03176906</CompanyNumber>
    <CapitalDocInd>0</CapitalDocInd>
    <SearchRows>4</SearchRows>
</FilingHistoryRequest>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to validate your document using Saxon as the schema processor, I get the following messages, with explanations interspersed.

```
Validation error on line 15 column 28 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "my pass" of element <Value> does not match the required simple
  type. Value "my pass" contravenes the pattern facet "[0-9a-f]{0,32}" of the type of element Value
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
```

I assume this is because you put a dummy password into the file for the purpose of your posting.

```
Validation error on line 18 column 27 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: The content "email company" of element <EmailAddress> does not match the
  required simple type. Value "email company" contravenes the pattern facet
  "[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_]{1,64}@[A-Za-z..." of the type of element EmailAddress
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#cvc-datatype-valid clause 1
```

Again, I assume you substituted a dummy email address.

```
Validation error on line 21 column 11 of test.xml:
  FORG0001: In content of element <GovTalkMessage>: The content model does not allow element
  <Q{.../govtalkheader}Body> to appear immediately after element
  <Q{.../govtalkheader}Header>. It must be preceded by <Q{.../govtalkheader}GovTalkDetails>. 
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
```

This error message is presumably the real problem. The message is saying pretty clearly that there is a missing element in your source, between Header and Body. The required element is present in GovTalk's sample XML message, but not in your version.

```
Warning 
  Schema at location http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/FilingHistory-v2-1.xsd
  has target namespace "" but requested namespace was "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema"
```

You should be using `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` rather than `xsi:schemaLocation` on the FilingHistoryRequest element. However, the GovTalk sample message contains the same error.

```
Warning 
  Validation will continue without the schema at
  http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/FilingHistory-v2-1.xsd
```

So Saxon is in effect ignoring the incorrect xsi:schemaLocation attribute.

Comment: hi Michael Kay
yes,i did not replace email,userid and pass with real information and this text in xml is example.
 i replace xsi:schemaLocation   with  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
but error not change

Comment: Did you fix the error I identified as being the real problem namely the missing GovTalkDetails element?

Comment: Why can't you fix the error? The schema requires a GovTalkDetails element, you aren't supplying one, so your request isn't working. So supply the missing element.

Comment: my xml is large you can give me your email?

Comment: It's easy to find my email address online, but I don't give off-list help to anyone other than paying customers. The deal on StackOverflow is that you get free help, but you are expected to make the effort to distill the essence of your problem into a short example.

Comment: hi thanks i fix the erore and send to company house .thanks for your help